# Drawing score on LibGDX/Java

Tags: java, android, mobile, libgdx, spritebatch

I make a catching to drops game but I should draw the users score on top left side of the screen. I use this code:

```
private SpriteBatch sayfa;
sayfa.begin();
scoreboard.draw(sayfa, score, 10,10);
sayfa.end();
```

But they aren't work because of you can only use string on scoreborad.draw method. How can I solve them.

Comment: Integer.toString(score)

Comment: ((int)score)+"" = string

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type score is, but this piece of code should work regardless of what primitve type score is (I'm assuming its primitive):

```
    String.valueOf(score);
```